# What in my code would cause my for loop to terminate prematurely? Am I missing "i" somewhere within the loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, terminate

I can't figure out what is causing my for loop to terminate. I just tried testing it and it only runs the print function. Then it just terminates. I can't see why it would do this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test092 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner usersVal = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        int valAdd = 0;
        System.out.println("Please provide a list of numbers");

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

            valAdd = Integer.valueOf(usersVal.nextInt());

            if (valAdd == -1) {
                break;
            }else {
                arrayList.add(valAdd);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect arrayList.size() to be?

Comment: A do while loop seems to be a lot more appropriate here than a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your arrayList doesn't have any elements in it. Therefore, when your loop checks `i < arrayList.size()` the loop does not run (since `arrayList.size()` is 0)

Comment: Ah thats it! I have changed it to be <= now to satisfy the condition.

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger since not using `i` and exiting loop with `break`, why not just use `for(;;)` (read as forever) or `while (true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try (Scanner usersVal = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Please provide a list of numbers");

        int valAdd = usersVal.nextInt();
        while (valAdd != -1) {
            arrayList.add(valAdd);
            valAdd = usersVal.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```